# Implemeneting IIS hosted WCF service with AzMan role provider

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis, authorization

I try to implement a WCF service that is hosted on IIS, the users ask for some templates files transformation and it return them the processed file (If they are authorized for the template they asked for). 
I selected the visual studio project template "WCF Service Application" and got a project with aspNetCompatibilityEnabled set to true etc.
I thought on implementing my need using AzMan authorization since I am fimiliar with that mechanism and did similiar things with it.
However, I can't debug the service since I get 401 unauthorized. 
I assume the user token is not being sent.

**1. How can I enable Azman usage for WCF, IIS hosted service? 

 2. Is there similiar mechanism embedded in WCF that can assist checking if a user belongs to a group that allowed to access some site folder?**

Confiuration:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="LocalPolicyStore"connectionString="msxml://c:/RolesData/azmanstore.xml" />             </connectionStrings>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
       <deny users="?" />
     </authorization>
     <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="RoleManagerAzManProvider" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookiePath="/" cookieTimeout="30" cookieRequireSSL="true" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieProtection="All">
   <providers>
    <add name="RoleManagerAzManProvider" type="System.Web.Security.AuthorizationStoreRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalPolicyStore" applicationName="DRP" />
  </providers>
 </roleManager>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" 
                      roleProviderName="RoleManagerAzManProvider" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="ExcelGeneratingService.ExcelGeneratorService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <endpoint
      address=""  
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="excelGeneratorServiceBinding"
      contract="ExcelGeneratingService.IExcelGeneratorService"/>
    <endpoint
        address="mex"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="excelGeneratorServiceBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
      </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"   multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
      To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

 </configuration>
```

Code:

```
     //Check if the user is allowed to access this path
     if (!UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(virtPath, user, "GET"))
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I hope it will help someone.

1. Some fixes to the configuration (Attached). All users allowed but filtered at lower level folders.
2. Installing missing authorization handlers at the IIS on the OS (Turn windows features on...)
3. Use the local IIS and not IIS Express from the visual studio
4. Clean the IIS Express configurations at the user data folder (C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config) if the IIS visrtual folder creation fails
5. Give my azman store a reader security privilege (at the azman console) for the service application pool user (from the IIS).

Configuration:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
         <add name="LocalPolicyStore" connectionString="msxml://c:/RolesData/ExcelGeneration.xml" />
          </connectionStrings>
          <appSettings>
             <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
          </appSettings>
       <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
       <authentication mode="Windows" />
       <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
       </authorization>
       <identity impersonate="false" />
       <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="RoleManagerAzManProvider" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookiePath="/" cookieTimeout="30" cookieRequireSSL="true" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieProtection="All">
         <providers>
           <add name="RoleManagerAzManProvider" type="System.Web.Security.AuthorizationStoreRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalPolicyStore" applicationName="ExcelGeneration" />
         </providers>
      </roleManager>
    </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
               <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"
        roleProviderName="RoleManagerAzManProvider" />
          </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="ExcelGeneratingService.ExcelGeneratorService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="excelGeneratorServiceBinding" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ExcelGeneratingService.IExcelGeneratorService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="excelGeneratorServiceBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
      </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

   <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <!--
          To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value  below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
       -->
     <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
   </system.webServer>
```